# How to program efficient undershoot/overshoot

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, code-request, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I would like to solve the following boundary value problem for $y(x)$ for a fixed value of $k$ between $0 < k <1$:

$$y'' + \frac{3}{x} y' - y + \frac{3}{2}y^2 - \frac{k}{2}y^3=0
\\
y'(0) = 0,\qquad y(\infty)\rightarrow0$$

To make this work, I truncate the domain of the problem to $x_0 < x < x_\text{Max}$ to avoid the singularity at $x=0$ and so that the second boundary condition is brought to a finite $y(x_\text{Max})=0$.  I will be working with $x_0 = 0.01$ and $x_\text{Max} = 10.$

I want to write a fast *Mathematica* program to solve this by using undershoot/overshoot on the related initial-value problem $y(x_0) = y_0$ to achieve the second boundary condition $y(x_\text{Max}) = 0$.

So far, I wrote a nice little code that solves the initial-value problem for a given $k$ and $y_0$:

```
sol = With[{x0 = .01, xMax = 10},
        ParametricNDSolveValue[
          {y''[x] + 3/x y'[x] - y[x] + 3/2 y[x]^2 - k/2 y[x]^3 == 0 (*diff.eq.*),
           y[x0] == y0 + 1/8 x0^2 (y0 - 3/2 y0^2 + k/2 y0^3)        (*init.cond.1*),
           y'[x0] == 1/4 x0 (y0 - 3/2 y0^2 + k/2 y0^3)              (*init.cond.2*),
           WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, {Print["Overshot"], "StopIntegration"}],
           WhenEvent[y'[x] == 0, {Print["Undershot"], "StopIntegration"}]
          },
          y, {x, x0, xMax}, {k, y0}]]
```

The solutions are obtained by calling `sol[k,y0][x]` and can be plotted by giving numbers for `k` and `y0`.

---

**Example**:  Take $k=0.4$

Then, $y_0 = 6.0$ (blue) leads to an "overshoot", $y_0 = 3.0$ (red) leads to an "undershoot", and $y_0 = 4.51114$ (black) is the "sweetspot" which gives the solution to the boundary value problem.

[image]

**Question:** What is the best way (in terms of performance) to automate getting the solution to the boundary value problem in *Mathematica*?

I definitely know that the correct $y_0$ lies somewhere between $\frac{3-\sqrt{9-8k}}{2k} < y_0 < \frac{3+\sqrt{9-8k}}{2k}$.

---

Appendix: the following code generates the graphic above.

```
plot1 = Plot[sol[0.4, 6][x], {x, .01, sol[0.4, 6]["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
plot2 = Plot[sol[0.4, 3][x], {x, .01, sol[0.4, 3]["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, PlotStyle -> Red];
plot3 = Plot[sol[0.4, 4.51114][x], {x, .01, sol[0.4, 4.51114]["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}];
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 6}}]
```

Comment: @ QuantumDot, how do you write the (*init.cond.1 and 2*), that is, `y[x0]` and `y'[x0]` as a polynomial in your code? Thanks!

Comment: @can It's the small `x` behavior of the solution at `x=x0`.  I can't start integration right at `x=0` because that is a singular point.

Comment: @ QuantumDot, I understand why you do this, but I cannot figure out how you do this. Could you give a hint, say, how $y(x_0)$ approximated as $y_0 + \frac{1}{8} x_0^2 (y_0 - \frac{3}{2} y_0^2 + \frac{k}{2} y_0^3)$. Sorry if it is a silly question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mundane but effective approach is to use the `Shooting` `Method` built into `NDSolve`.

```
x0 = .01; xMax = 11.5; k = .4;
c = N[D[(BesselK[1, x]/x), x]/(BesselK[1, x]/x) /. x -> xMax];
sol = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + 3/x y'[x] - y[x] + 3/2 y[x]^2 - 
     k/2 y[x]^3 == 0, y'[xMax] == c y[xMax], y'[x0] == 0}, y, {x, x0, xMax}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[x0] == 4.5, y'[x0] == 0}}]
```

Note that the boundary condition `y'[xMax] == c y[xMax]` is employed to match the exponentially decreasing asymptotic solution to the ODE, `BesselK[1, x]/x`.  Also, `xMax` is increased to `11.5`.

The `k = .4` solution, compared to that given in the question is,

```
LogPlot[{sol[x], solt[x]}, {x, x0, xMax}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Two features are evident.  First, the solution already is exponentially decreasing at `x = 3`.  Second, both approaches become unstable, the method in the Question at about `x = 9.5` and that given here at about `x = 11`.  This presumably occurs due to unavoidable round-off errors that couple into the second, exponentially growing, asymptotic solution to the ODE.

The value of `y` near the origin agrees quite closely with that in the Question.

```
sol[x0]
(* 4.51095 *)
```

The next plot depicts `y[x0]` (points) as a function of `k`, along with the bounds on `y[x0]` (solid curves) given in the Question.  (These bounds correspond to the values of `y[x0]` which satisfy the ODE for all `x`, apart from the boundary condition at infinity.)

```
data = {{0., 5.78018}, {0.1, 5.49104}, {0.2, 5.18459}, {0.3, 4.85871}, {0.4, 4.51095}, 
        {0.5, 4.13862}, {0.6, 3.73916}, {0.7, 3.31151}, {0.75, 3.08818}, 
        {0.8, 2.86076}, {0.85, 2.63322}, {0.88, 2.49923}, {0.9, 2.41187}};
Show[ListPlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"k", y[0]}, PlotStyle -> Black], 
  Plot[{(3 - Sqrt[9 - 8 k])/(2 k), (3 + Sqrt[9 - 8 k])/(2 k)}, {k, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Black], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 6}}]
```

[image]

Solutions for `k < .8` are obtained with moderate ease by first running the code above with `xMax = 5`, which is fairly forgiving of inaccurate initial guesses for `y[x0]`, and then using the resulting actual `y[x0]` with `xMax = 10` to obtain `y[x0]` accurate to five significant figures or better.  The process becomes rather more delicate at larger `k`, because `y[0`] lies very close to its upper bound.  I typically would need to guess about five times (moving the point at which `NDSolve` declared the equations stiff toward `xMax`) and also increase `xMax` somewhat to obtain a solution that was both stable and accurate.  Any particular calculation takes less than a second of computer time.

A comparison among `y` for `k` of `0`(blue), `.6`(brown), `.8`(green), and `.9` (red) follows.  That the `k = 0.9` solution is essentially constant out to about `x = 10` explains why the calculation at larger `k` is so delicate and also why `xMax = 15` is necessary for accuracy.

[image]

Note that I have not experimented with `NDSolve` `Method`s for handling stiffness, which may improve the robustness of this solution.  Nonetheless, I was able to obtain the curves above without excessive difficulty.

Comment: I have mathematica 9, and I can't get your solution to work for any value of $k$ except for 0.4.  I *always* get "stiff system" errors.

Comment: @QuantumDot  I have added information to my answer to assist you in obtaining solutions for various `k` and also corrected a minor (and numerically inconsequential) error in the upper boundary condition.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, a digression: I am interested in how to estimate or obtain the **asymptotic solution** to the ODE. If I use `DSolve[3/x y'[x] - y[x] == 0, y[x], x]`, it gives `(*y[x] -> E^(x^2/6) C[1]*)`

Comment: @can  Because we are seeking the asymptotic solution that goes to zero for large `x`, drop the nonlinear terms in the ODE and solve with `DSolve`.  It returns `{y[x] -> -((BesselJ[1, I x] C[1])/x) + (BesselY[1, -I x] C[2])/x}`, and an appropriate choice of the two constants yields `BesselK[1, x]/x`, which satisfies the `y[Infinity] == 0` boundary condition.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thanks again for your explanation. You appear to know all the maths about numerical and analytical one!

Comment: @QuantumDot   Having forgotten the details of your question, I inadvertently solved your equation once again as an answer to [116130](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116130/1063).  (Old age, perhaps.)  The result is slightly more accurate and is better automated.