# Solving an ODE using shooting method

Tags: differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the following nonlinear ordinary differential equation:

$$-\Phi''-\frac{3}{r}\Phi'+\Phi-\frac{3}{2}\Phi^{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\Phi^{3}=0$$

with boundary conditions

$$\Phi'(0)=0,\Phi(\infty)=0.$$

My solution is supposed to reproduce the following plots:

[image]

Now, to produce the plots given above, I wrote the following Mathematica code:

```
α = 0.99;
Φlower = 0;
Φupper = 5;
For[counter = 0, counter <= 198, counter++,
    Φ0 = (Φlower + Φupper)/2;
    r0 = 0.00001;
    Φr0 = Φ0 + (1/16) (r0^2) (2 (Φ0) - 3 (Φ0^2) + α (Φ0^3));
    Φpr0 = (1/8) (r0) (2 (Φ0) - 3 (Φ0^2) + α (Φ0^3));
    diffeq = {-Φ''[r] - (3/r) Φ'[r] + Φ[r] - (3/2) (Φ[r]^2) + (α/2) (Φ[r]^3) == 0, Φ[r0] == Φr0, Φ'[r0] == Φpr0};
    sol = NDSolve[diffeq, Φ, {r, r0, 200}, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];
    Φtest = Φ[200] /. sol[[1]];
    Φupper = If[(Φtest < 0) ||   (Φtest > 1.2), Φ0, Φupper];
    Φlower = If[(Φtest < 1.2) && (Φtest > 0),   Φ0, Φlower];
]
Plot[Evaluate[{Φ[r]} /. sol[[1]]], {r, 0, 200}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

In the code, I used Taylor expansion at $r=0$ due to the $-\frac{3}{r}\Phi'$ term. Moreover, I used shooting method and continually bisected an initial interval from $\Phi_{\text{upper}}=5$ to $\Phi_{\text{lower}}=0$ to obtain more and more precise values of $\Phi(0)$.

With the code above, I was able to produce the plots for $\alpha = 0.50, 0.90, 0.95,0.96,0.97$. For example, my plot for $\alpha = 0.50$ is as follows:

[image]

However, my plot for $\alpha = 0.99$ does not converge to the required plot:

[image]

Can you suggest how I might tackle this problem for $\alpha = 0.99$? Also, is there an explanation for the plots shooting upwards and oscillating after a prolonged asymptotic trend towards the positive $r$-axis?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Now that you mention it, I think my question is not really about the technical details of Mathematica, but rather about the implementation technique of an ODE problem. So, would you suggest me to delete it?

Comment: In any event: what happens if you use a different method, like `"StiffnessSwitching"`?

Comment: I would expect `Φ[0]` to be `(3 + Sqrt[9 - 8 α])/(2 α)`.

Comment: @ Guess who it is: I tried "Stiffness Switching", bit it does not work for some reason.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey: I understand that you calculated $\Phi[0]=(3 + \sqrt{9 - 8 \alpha})/(2 \alpha)$ using the cubic equation in the differential equation. But, that value of $\Phi[0]$ actually leads to an equilibrium solution - the solution does not tend to $0$ as $r$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: The identical equation is solved in question [84131](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84131/how-to-program-efficient-undershoot-overshoot/84300#84300)