# Undershoot/Overshoot Method for this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have tried to solve this equation for some weeks and I am not capable. I have read in articles that it is easy with an undershoot/overshoot method, but I don't know how to do it.

$y''+\frac{3}{x}y'-y+\frac{3}{2}y^2-\frac{k}{2}y^3=0$

where $k$ is a constant $0<k<1$.

With the following boundary conditions: $y'(0)=0$ and $y(r)=0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty $

There are problems at $x=0$ but they can be avoided starting $x_i=0.001$.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For small `k`,

```
xs = 10^-4; xm = 12;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] + 3 y'[x]/x - y[x] + 3/2 y[x]^2 - k y[x]^3/2 == 0, 
    y'[xs] == 0, y[xm] == 0}, y, {x, xs, xm}, {k, ys}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[xs] == ys, y'[xs] == 0}}];    

f = y[.2, 5.2] /. s;
f[xs]
Plot[f[x], {x, xs, xm}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> All]
```

works well.

```
(* 5.18512 *)
```

[image]

**Addendum - Results at Larger k**

Results at larger `k` can be obtained by extrapolating the `Shooting` parameter, `ys` from lower values of `k`.  A simple approach is

```
start = {{0.01, (y[.01, 5.77] /. s)[xs]}, {0.02, (y[.02, 5.74] /. s)[xs]}};
Do[tem = 2 start[[i - 1, 2]] - start[[i - 2, 2]]; 
    new = {N[i/100], (y[i/100, tem] /. s)[xs]}; AppendTo[start, new], {i, 3, 86}]
ListLinePlot[start, AxesLabel -> {k, "ys"}]
```

[image]

This iterative calculation fails for still larger `k`, because progressively larger values of `xm` are needed as `k` is increased.  This is evident from the final result here, at `k == 0.86`.

```
f = y @@ Last @ start /. s;
f[xs]
Plot[f[x], {x, xs, xm}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> All]

(* 2.58848 *)
```

[image]

To proceed further, a more sophisticated extrapolation process is needed, probably one that extrapolates `xm` as well as `ys`.  Note, however, that the `NDSolve` computation rapidly becomes more delicate as `xm` is increased.  It seems likely that a practical limit for this approach will be encountered at `k` of order `0.90`.  Still, most of the desired parameter range can be covered in this way.

**Second Addendum - Improved Code, Slightly Larger k**

At large `x`, where y[x] is to be very small, the nonlinear terms in the ODE can be ignored, yielding a solution proportional to `BesselK[1, x]/x`, as can be verified by

```
FullSimplify[Unevaluated[D[y[x], x, x] + 3 D[y[x], x]/x - y[x]] /. y[x] -> BesselK[1, x]/x]
(* 0 *)
```

Consequently, an improved boundary condition for large but finite `x` is

```
y'[xm] == c y[xm]
```

where

```
c = FullSimplify[Unevaluated[D[y[x], x]/y[x]] /. y[x] -> BesselK[1, x]/x]
(* -BesselK[2, xm]/BesselK[1, xm] *)
```

(and `x` has been replaced by `xm`).

To obtain larger values of `k`, insert the new boundary condition into the `ParametricNDSolve` expression and increase `xm`,

```
xs = 10^-4; xm = 17; c = -BesselK[2, xm]/BesselK[1, xm];
s = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] + 3 y'[x]/x - y[x] + 3/2 y[x]^2 - k y[x]^3/2 == 0, 
    y'[xs] == 0, y'[xm] == c y[xm]}, y, {x, xs, xm}, {k, ys}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
   "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[xs] == ys, y'[xs] == 0}}];
```

and take smaller steps, here `0.005`, in the extrapolation loop above.  A new version of the loop, using `While` to check for `NDSolve` errors, is

```
start = {{0.005, (y[0.005, 5.7672] /. s)[xs]}, {0.010, (y[0.010, 5.75306] /. s)[xs]}}; 
new = 1; i = 3;
While[new != 0 && start[[i - 1, 1]] <= 1, tem = 2 start[[i - 1]] - start[[i - 2]]; 
    new = Quiet@Check[(y @@ tem /. s)[xs], 0]; If[new != 0, 
    AppendTo[start, {First@tem, new}]]; i++]
First@Last@start
ListLinePlot[start, AxesLabel -> {k, "ys"}]

(* 0.9 *)
```

and the second plot, above, is essentially unchanged.  Thus, all this has increased the maximum value of `k` only from `0.88` to `0.9`.  However, the computation takes only about `17 sec` on my computer, so further effort probably can produce *slightly* larger values of `k`.  To see why it is difficult to obtain solutions for `k` approaching `9/8`, plot the solution for `k == 0.9`.  (See next Addendum for derivation of this maximum value.)

[image]

Although this curve looks quite similar to the one above for `k = 0.88`, the full width at half-maximum (FWHM) is about `11` here and only about `8` there.  I speculate that FWHM approaches infinity as `k` approaches `9/8`.

**Third Addendum - Larger k Analytical Expression; Duplicate Question**

I was somewhat embarrassed to realize an hour ago that I had already solved the equation in this Question almost precisely a year ago as [Question 84131](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84300/1063), although the present derivaton is more accurate and better automated.  The earlier answer noted that derivatives of `y[x]` nearly vanish at small `x` for larger `k`, such as for `k == 0.9` in the fourth plot above.  Dropping the derivatives and solving the resulting algebraic equation yields,

```
a = Solve[-ys + 3/2 ys^2 - k ys^3/2 == 0, ys][[3, 1]]
(* ys -> (3 + Sqrt[9 - 8 k])/(2 k) *)
```

which evaluates to `ys == 2.41202` for `k == 0.9`.  This differs from the numerical value of `ys`,

```
f = y @@ Last@start /. s; f[xs]
(* 2.41187 *)
```

by only one part in `10^4`, but this is sufficient that `ys == 2.41202` is not a good initial guess for computing the `k == 0.9` curve, again indicating how delicate the `NDSolve` computation is for larger `k`.  The analytical estimate (in red), superimposed on the numerical results for `ys` (in blue), is given by

```
Show[ListLinePlot[start, AxesLabel -> {k, "ys"}], 
    Plot[ys /. a, {k, 0, 9/8}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Red]], 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 6}}]
```

[image]

The maximum theoretical value of `k` is `9/8`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Anyway, I'm trying to get something more general. For each k there should is only one y[0] that satisfies the equation with the boundary conditions. So the interesting thing is obtaining this value taking into account the boundary conditions I mentioned earlier. Thank you very much again!

Comment: @jca17  Computed `y[xs]` as requested.  Also, increased `xm` and fixed typo.  I can solve for `k` as large as `0.6` without difficulty and undoubtedly can reach larger values.  I should add that integrating a nonlinear ODE along its separatrix can be very difficult, and evidently this become more so for your equation as `k` is increased.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I estimate the initial shooting parameter? Because with 5.2 all goes well, but with 5.3 nope :(. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @jca17  Use trial and error to obtain a few solutions for small `k`, and then use them to estimate starting values for larger `k`.  I am modifying the code now to make it a bit simpler for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!! I will try to improve the stability for larger values of k.

Comment: Thank you for that improvement!! Anyway, I am not capable of obtaining a solution putting xm=17. I think I dont really understand that new boundary condition you have mentioned.

Comment: @jca17  Setting y[x] equal to zero is valid as a boundary condition only in the limit that x goes to infinity.  For large by finite `x`, setting the logarithmic derivative (y'/y) of `y[x]` equal to the logarithmic derivative of `BesselK[1, x]/x]` is more accurate.  Typically, this improvement is insignificant except for large `k`.  See also my final Addendum.  I had completely forgotten that I had solved your equation once before.

Comment: Thank you very much again! Sorry but I am not able of improving the code as you said in the second Addendum. I am taking taking the code of Addendum 1, defining c=N[D[(BesselK[1, x]/x), x]/(BesselK[1, x]/x) /. x -> xm], changing the boundary value at the ParameterSolution, and increasing xf to xf=17. Then, I run the NDSolve and it is impossible to continue after x=12.5.

Comment: @jca17  To avoid ambiguity, I inserted a block of code into Second Addendum. Just copy the code beginning xs = 10^-4; xm = 17; ... and the next block of code beginning start = ... and you should be able to reproduce my results.  With `xm = 18` and the initial `start = {{0.001, (y[0.001, 5.77848] /. s)[xs]}, {0.002, (y[0.002, 5.77566] /. s)[xs]}}`, I pushed as far as 0.92.  Going further will be challenging, unless you choose to use the analytical expression in Third Addendum, which is quite accurate as such large `k`.  Please do not forget to accept my answer, if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: Thank you, the code works perfectly, I think that the errors come from defining some parameters. Of course I will accept your answer, 200% satisfactory.