# Stiff second order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I am trying to solve numerically $f''=f^{3}-f$, whose exact solution is $\tanh(x)$.
The problem is that numerical solution fails if I come closer to $\tanh$ plateau. `"StiffnessSwitching"` method doesn't help.

```
fff = NDSolve[{f''[x] == f[x]^3 - f[x], f[-3] == 1, f[3] == -1}, f[x],
               {x, -3, 3}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
N[Tanh[3]]
```

> ```
> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == -2.29166, step size is effectively zero;
> singularity or stiff system suspected.
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the solution is `Tanh`? `FullSimplify[(f''[x] - f[x]^3 + f[x]) /. {f -> 
    Function[{x}, Tanh[x]]}] = -Sech[x]^2 Tanh[x]`

Comment: Direct Calculation : $ Tanh''[x]=-2 Sech[x]^2 Tanh[x]=Tanh[x]^3-Tanh[x]$Divide on tanh u see $Sech[x]^2=1-Tanh[x]^2 $ u get  identity.

Comment: According to Mathematica: `FullSimplify[Tanh[x]^3 - Tanh[x]]==-Sech[x]^2 Tanh[x]`. You miss a factor 2 in the RHS of your equation.

Comment: Ops, i see, will try now.

Comment: well, this not removed stiffness `fff = NDSolve[{f''[x] == 2 (f[x]^3 - f[x]), f[-3] == 1, f[3] == -1}, 
  f[x], {x, -3, 3}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]` NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.3758850281121969`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

Comment: Why are you playing with `NDSolve` since one can get exact solutions with `DSolve`?

Comment: @Artes, likely a toy problem, and his actual problem has a qualitatively similar solution.

Comment: @Artes  `DSolve` gives me a solution (in terms of `JacobiSN`), only when I discard the boundary conditions, in which case I am left with two unknown constants that are not easy to evaluate.  Have you done better?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Those constants are simply expressible in terms of the boundary conditions and appropriate combinations of `JacobiSN`'s yields solutions in terms of `Tanh`. I wish the original  poster would clearly point out the actual problem.

Comment: @Artes  Right, you are: `C[1] == 1` and `C[2] == 0`.  Thanks.  The OP gave his actual question in a comment to my answer below, and I then added a sample calculation of it to my answer.  However, I have not tried to obtain results for larger `α`.

Comment: @bb, `Tanh[]` is actually what `JacobiSN[]` will degenerate to if its second argument is `1`, FYI.

Comment: Generally speaking, an NDSolve::ndsz error in a (nonsingular, non-stiff) BVP is (most likely) coming from a singularity developing in the initial conditions chosen by the built-in shooting method used by NDSolve. Explicitly setting "StartingInitialConditions" can help, when possible. So can manually implementing the shooting method. (This should be better known/advertised.  It's come up several times.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equation is not stiff, despite the claim by Mathematica.  It can be solved by using the "Shooting" `Method`.

```
NDSolve[{f''[x] == 2 (f[x]^3 - f[x]), f[-3] == 1, f[3] == -1}, f, {x, -3, 3}, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[-3] == 1, f'[-3] == 0}}][[1, 1]];
Plot[f[x] /. %, {x, -3, 3}, AxesLabel -> {f, x}]
```

[image]

This looks like a plot of `-Tan[x]` but is not precisely that because of the boundary conditions.

**Addendum - Sample Solution for Question in Comment**

[satoru](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/40622/satoru) describes a much more difficult problem in a comment below.  A sample solution to it is

```
xm = 10;
NDSolve[{f''[x] == f[x]^3 - f[x] + α f[x] (1 - Tanh[x])^2, 
    f[-xm] == Sqrt[1 - 2 α], f[xm] == -1} /. α -> 10^-6, f, {x, -xm, xm}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[xm] == -1, f'[xm] == 0}}][[1, 1]];
Plot[f[x] /. %, {x, -xm, xm}, AxesLabel -> {f, x}]
```

[image]

Note how the `Tanh`-like solution is shifted to the left even for tiny `α`.  Solutions for larger `a` probably can be obtained by centering the integration range on the value of `x` for which `f[x] == Sqrt[1 - 2 α] - 1`, and obtaining an estimate for that quantity by extrapolating results from smaller values of `α`.  See, for instance, the automated process in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116130/1063).

Comment: Wow, this realy works! But the new question is what to do if i dont know exact solution and cant use precise boundary conditions? Real problem is $f''=f^{3}-f+\alpha f(1-Tanh[x])^{2}$ I know how solution behaves on infinities, external field part becomes constant and i have equation i wrote above. So $f[-\infty]=-\sqrt{1-2\alpha}Tanh[\sqrt{1-2\alpha}(-\infty)]=\sqrt{1-2\alpha}$ and $f[\infty]=-1$ In my first example i used 3 instead of infinity as some big number, Tanh[3] is near one, and this dont work, how to plug infinities in boundary conditions?

Comment: @satoru  I was careless in my answer.  Actually, boundary conditions using `Tanh[]`are not needed.  I shall correct my answer in a few minutes.  The question you pose in your comment is much harder.  Usually, choosing some large value instead of infinity is sufficient for the boundary conditions.  What value of alpha would you like?

Comment: @bbgodfrey i began from small alpha (and sign before external part must be -), but something is wrong : `a = 5
\[Alpha] = 0.1
s = NDSolve[{f''[x] == 
    2 *(f[x]^3 - f[x]) - \[Alpha]*f[x]*(1 - Tanh[x])^2, 
   f[-a] == -Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]] Tanh[-a*Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]]], 
   f[a] == -Tanh[a]}, f, {x, -a, a}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[-a] == -Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]]
          Tanh[-a*Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]]], f'[-a] == 0}}]
Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. s], {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All]` stiffness report

Comment: I also noticed if a use too large a (about 10) even with alpha=0 and exact boundary conditions solution becomes wrongly dislocated from x=0

Comment: @satoru  Use `WorkingPrecision -> 30` to solve the `a == 10` problem, although the code runs much slower.  I am not surprised that `α == 0.1` fails.  Try `α == 10^-6` and you will already see a large shift.  I shall post the latter answer, but solving your problem more generally will be quite difficult.

Comment: with $\alpha=10^-8$ i got solution `a = 10
\[Alpha] = \
0.00000009000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
0000000000000000000000
s = NDSolve[{f''[x] == 
    2 *(f[x]^3 - f[x]) - \[Alpha]*f[x]*(1 - Tanh[x])^2, 
   f[-a] == -Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]] Tanh[-a*Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]]], 
   f[a] == -Tanh[a]}, f, {x, -a, a}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[-a] == -Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]]
          Tanh[-a*Sqrt[1 + 2 \[Alpha]]], f'[-a] == 0}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxSteps -> 100000]
Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. s], {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @satoru  I am not quite sure how to interpret your last comment.  See my answer for a solution for `α == 10^-6`.  I do not have time to do more now.

Comment: its simply shifted kink, but the interest is $a>>1$ and looks like its heavy numerical problem. I got insight what i can find new variable, to make interval of integration finite. But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: @satoru, please edit your question to include the problem you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];

sol = NDSolve[{f''[x] == f[x]^3 - f[x], f[-3] == 1, f[3] == -1}, f[x], {x, -3, 3}, 
Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 1}}];
```

**UPDATE:**

**Maples** symbolic solution`(The symbolic solution is quite long and complex)` ,converted to numeric form.`Maple` gives **5** solutions other than `Mathematica`.
[image]

Maples `JacobiSN[z,k]` is equal to Mathematica `JacobiSN[z,k^2]`.

With `20` digits precision.

```
maple1 = (-1.5279997865913399554 - 0.58636062345487262098*I)*
JacobiSN[(0.94894046904339260202 - 
  0.94416766565747605255*I)*(0.70710678118654752440*x + 
  1.6985155326343786960 - 
  0.20793350722877537103*I), (-0.50021641106619559220 - 
  1.1156113783217666782*I)^2]; 
maple2 = (-0.57150532368340334446 - 
0.87200104339127158745*I)*
JacobiSN[(1.5911818830635583675 - 
  0.31319690342130914617*I)*(0.70710678118654752440*x + 
  1.7471798211151876014 + 
  0.44795429731942814652*I), (-0.24192870056640322887 - 
  0.59564049424232431474*I)^2];
maple3 = (-1.5279997865913399554 - 
0.58636062345487262098*I)*
JacobiSN[(0.94894046904339260202 - 
  0.94416766565747605255*I)*(0.70710678118654752440*x + 
  1.6985155326343786960 - 
  0.20793350722877537103*I), (-0.50021641106619559220 - 
  1.1156113783217666782*I)^2]; 
maple4 = (-1.5279997865913399554 - 
0.58636062345487262098*I)*
JacobiSN[(0.94894046904339260202 - 
  0.94416766565747605255*I)*(0.70710678118654752440*x + 
  1.6985155326343786960 - 
  0.20793350722877537103*I), (-0.50021641106619559220 - 
  1.1156113783217666782*I)^2]; 
maple5 = (-1.5279997865913399554 + 
0.58636062345487262098*I)*
JacobiSN[(0.94894046904339260202 + 
  0.94416766565747605255*I)*(0.70710678118654752440*x + 
  1.6985155326343786960 + 
  0.20793350722877537103*I), (-0.50021641106619559220 + 
  1.1156113783217666782*I)^2];
```

.

Boundary conditions check:

```
  Re[{maple1, maple2, maple3, maple4, maple5}] /. x -> -3 // N
  (*{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}*)
  Re[{maple1, maple2, maple3, maple4, maple5}] /. x -> 3 // N
  (*{-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.}*)
```

.

```
  Plot[{Re[maple1], Re[maple2], Re[maple2], Re[maple2], Re[maple2], 
  f[x] /. sol}, {x, -3, 3}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"maple1", "maple2", "maple3", "maple4", "maple5", 
  "NDSOLVE"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, {Green, Dashing[{0.2, 0.05}], 
  Thickness[0.01]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.01], 
  Dashing[{0.3, 0.1}]}, {Black, Thickness[0.01], 
  Dashing[{0.1, 0.1}]}, Yellow, Brown}, AxesLabel -> {x, f[x]}]
```

[image]

Comment: How you converted the long symbolic expression into numeric in maple?

Comment: @MMM. I use a `evalf` command.

Comment: Have you checked the residual error of Maple's solution (with precision higher than `MachinePrecision`)?

Comment: @xzczd .It seems that everything is ok.Yes i checked.Boundary conditions ok.

Answer (score 3):

In versiion 12.0 you can use the nonlinear FEM solver:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{f''[x] == f[x]^3 - f[x], f[-3] == 1, f[3] == -1}, 
  f[x], {x, -3, 3}, Method -> "FiniteElement"]
Plot[sol, {x, -3, 3}, AxesLabel -> {f, x}]
```

[image]